# How to change the order in which a file's text is inserted in Tkinter Text Widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to make a text editor with Python 3.4.2 and tkinter/ttk. When my file is loaded in, the text is inserted into the Text widget from the bottom of the file up, making the file text "backwards". The last line of the file is inserted first, and the first line last. Anything will help. Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os

class Main(Frame):
  def __init__(self, master):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

  def create_widgets(self):
    self.body = Text(self, width=50, height=15)
    self.body.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.save_label = Label(self, text="File to Save to:")
    self.save_label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.save_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
    self.save_entry.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.save_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Save File", command=self.save)
    self.save_button.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.read_label = Label(self, text="File to Read:")
    self.read_label.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.read_entry = ttk.Entry(self)
    self.read_entry.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.read_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Read File", command=self.read)
    self.read_button.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.body.yview)
    scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = int(1), sticky = 'ns')
    self.body.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    self.quit_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.close)
    self.quit_button.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)

  def close(self):
    root.destroy()
    quit()

  def save(self):
    body = self.body.get('0.0', 'end-1c')
    file = self.save_entry.get()

    file = open(file, "w")
    file.write(body)
    file.close()

  def read(self):
    self.body.delete("0.0", END)
    file = self.read_entry.get()

    file = open(file, 'r')
    file_data = file.readlines()

    for i in file_data:
      self.body.insert('1.0', str(i))

    file.close()

root = Tk()
root.title("NotePad")
root.geometry("500x600")
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
app = Main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are telling tkinter to place each line at `"1.0"`. If you want each line to be added to the end, use `"end"`

```
for i in file_data:
  self.body.insert('end', str(i))
```

---

By the way, the first character of a text widget is at `"1.0"`, not `"0.0"`. While `"0.0"` will work as quirk of how tkinter is implemented, the correct index is `"1.0"`.

For example, use this:

```
body = self.body.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
```

... rather than this:

```
body = self.body.get('0.0', 'end-1c')
```

Comment: my first post was using the END keyword, but i noticed the text was wrapping with long lines, whats the difference with 'end' ? (obviously the wrapping is due to the geometry)

Comment: @PRMoureu: `"end"` means "at the end of the document". That's all. There's nothing special about it. The tkinter constant `END` is simply the string `"end"`